# 'Gradle sync failed: Gradle DSL method not found: 'minSdkVersdion()'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Gradle sync failed: Gradle DSL method not found: 'minSdkVersdion(). I am using latest version of Android studio 2.0.

Here is my updated gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.gkhindi'
    minSdkVersdion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName '1.0.0'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
}
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

dependencies {
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 compile files('libs/StartAppInApp-3.1.0.jar')
 compile files('libs/Shutterbug-1.0.0.jar')
 compile files('libs/Parse-1.11.0.jar')
 compile files('libs/bolts-tasks-1.3.0.jar')
//    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:8.4.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
 compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
}
android {
  useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

This is my final gradle. When i syn the gradle then I am receiving the error is 'Gradle sync failed: Gradle DSL method not found: 'minSdkVersdion()'.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your `build.gradle`

```
minSdkVersdion 16
```

instead of

```
minSdkVersion 16
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gaberile

Comment: @user3144577 Mark the answer if it solves you issue.